# Seifert-Van Kampen Theorem Application

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[image]

Given above diagram how can we calculate the fundamental group? I thought we could apply Seifert-Van Kampen. Thus we need to decide open path connected $U$ and $V$. What is a good choice for $U$ and $V$? Here is my attempt.

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to calculate the fundamental group of $V$.

Comment: Consider the region $\mathcal P$ as in the first picture. There is a deformation retract of $\mathcal P$ to its boundary by radial projection starting from the center of the circle $d$. Compose this deformation retract with the quotient map of the surface, and this will give a deformation retract of the surface to the wedge of three circles given by $[a]\lor[b]\lor [c]=\Bbb S^1\lor \Bbb S^1\lor \Bbb S^1$. Hence, the fundamental group of this surface is $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta Thank you for your comment. I want to use Seifert Van-Kampen. I added my attempt in the post. Could you check my answer? Also I am having trouble calculating the fundamental group of $V$.

Comment: I have given the solution for fundamental group $q(V)$, where $q$ is the quotient map.

Comment: That is your $V$ is my $\mathcal P$.

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta Now I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that I have computed the fundamental group of $q(V)$.